# Why isn't the 'or' operand working as intended?

Tags: python, if-statement, operands

For the code below:

```
string = "Hello everybody!"

if 'Hippo' or 'Monkey' in string:
    print("Found a hippo or monkey in my string")
```

the if statement is returning true. Why is this?

Comment: Tag the question with the language and compiler you're using. And make sure you format it so that it can be compiled by someone else. Please don't make others work harder to help you than is absolutely necessary.

Comment: What language would that be? But generally this condition should be written as `if 'Hippo' in string or ' Monkey' in string` in most languages

Comment: @derpirscher Ah sorry, that would be in Python. Thank you for helping! This looks to be working as intended now.

Comment: Please add the tag to the question. Don't just add a comment. The system understands tags. It doesn't use AI to read comments.

Comment: The semantics you seem to expect would require `... or ... in ...` to be a *single* expression, but it's not. It's just two separate expressions (combined with `or`, because `in` has higher precedence), and each expression has its own semantics the produce *values* that are then operated on by `or`.

Comment: Compare to `x < y < z`, which *is* a single expression, with three operands `x`, `y`, and `z`, rather than one `<` expression being used as the operand for a second.

Comment: Why did you close the question? It's a good question, you should allow answers not just comments

Comment: @Elliptica because the linked question handles more or less the same problem so it doesn't make any sense to add answers here when the correct answer is given already somewhere else ...